# Trying to share a json string in a file with an activity view controller

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

iOS 11, Swift 4
Trying to use an activity view controller to share a json string I have just created, and I think I am almost there, but struggling to attach a file with the controller. I got this code.

```
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    if let jsonData = try? encoder.encode(w2GA) {
        if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
            let documentsDirectoryURL = try! FileManager().url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
            let file2ShareURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("blah.json")
            print(jsonString)
            do {
                let encodedData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(jsonString)
                try encodedData?.write(to: file2ShareURL)
                    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [file2ShareURL], applicationActivities: nil)
                    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
                    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting the error message:

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FD6E9F52-405F-4E66-927F-DCB7EDB0BF25/Documents/blah.json
>
> ## Attachments Error confirming URL is readable

Pretty sure the file is there? is this some sort of race hazard perhaps? If I replace the URL with the jsonString it works! So I get a jsonString looking like this basically.

> [{"imageURL":"http://","latitude":46.819945794990176,"name":"Clue 1","longitude":8.2581710034376599,"hint":"Hint"},{"imageURL":"http://","latitude":47.433033706679716,"name":"Clue 2","longitude":8.8540648624925371,"hint":"Hint"},{"imageURL":"http://","latitude":46.785125219263776,"name":"Clue","longitude":9.6534346734197598,"hint":"Hint"}]

Comment: Try replacing `let documentsDirectoryURL = try! FileManager().url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)` with `let documentsDirectoryURL = try! FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!`

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to save this as a file?

Surely the simplest approach to this is to pass the JSON string as a variable?

Example:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [jsonString], applicationActivities: nil)
```

**EDIT**

I've just noticed you've already tried this and it works. Apologies.

Ensure the `JSONEncoder` isn't throwing an exception and that the file exists before you try to pass the url to the `UIActivityViewController`

You can also try using the `UIActivityItemProvider` class as documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityitemprovider?changes=_4&language=objc)

Comment: Yes, I can do. But than the message is a json string and it is more difficult to deal with by a novice at the other end. As a file I can simply airdrop it and use it, as a string with an email, no not so obvious.

Comment: I've just edited my answer. Hopefully that'll provide some help

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found the answer which is of course obvious! The file wasn't being created!

I made two changes, firstly I run the entire code block under the main thread, secondly I changed the lines writing out the json string which in the earlier version I encode twice!

```
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        if let jsonData = try? encoder.encode(w2GA) {
            if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
                var documentsDirectoryURL = try! FileManager().url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
                let file2ShareURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("blah.json")
                do {
                    try jsonString.write(to: file2ShareURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }

                do {
                    let _ = try Data(contentsOf: file2ShareURL)
                    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [file2ShareURL], applicationActivities: nil)
                    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
                    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of this line? 

    let _ = try Data(contentsOf: file2ShareURL)